# Compare list in LINQ and return 2 result objects

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 Lists: `List<Car> newCars` and `List<Car> oldCars`.

I need to use the `List<Car> newCars` as the source of truth and return both **Present** and **Absent** cars in the `List<Car>oldCars` list.

How can I do this?

My approach:

```
var present = newCars.Where(c => oldCars.All(w => w.Id != c.Id));
var absent = newCars.Where(c => oldCars.All(w => w.Id == c.Id));
```

I am quite new to LINQ, and I am not sure of the logic that I have used above.

1. Can someone help me out to get this working in a better and optimized way?
2. Can this be done in one single query and return 2 result sets (as tuples)?

I realize that running the same code with equals and not equals as above can be a costly approach.

Comment: [Equi-join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/method-based-query-syntax-examples-join-linq-to-dataset#join) and [left join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/perform-left-outer-joins).

Comment: If you need two resulting lists, use a normal for/foreach loop. Fill both in one pass.

Comment: look into the Intersect method of the List Class.  this will return common elements in 2 lists and return the results in a new list.

Comment: First I would get a list of all `Car` objects which match using LINQ. Then you can use `List.Contains(item) == false` in a loop

Comment: Should'nt absent be utilizing `Any` instead of `All`

Comment: Your statement of the present and absent seems ambiguous, based on your code I assume you want to split the `newCars` list into cars present in `oldCars` and cars absent from `oldCars`, in which case you should have `Any` instead of `All` - obviously `oldCars.All` will only be true if `oldCars` contains one car.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create custom `IEqualityComparer`:

```
public class CarEqualityComparer : IEqualityComparer<Car>
{
    public bool Equals(Car x, Car y)
    {
        return x.Id == y.Id;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Car obj)
    {
        return obj.Id.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var present = newCars.Intersect(oldCars, new CarEqualityComparer());
var absent = newCars.Except(oldCars, new CarEqualityComparer());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can utilize an anonymous variable containing the two lists:

```
var res = new
{
    present = newCars.Where(n => oldCars.Select(o => o.Id).Contains(n.Id)), // present if the old cars list contains the id from the new list
    absent = newCars.Where(n => !oldCars.Select(o => o.Id).Contains(n.Id)) // absent if the old cars list does not contain the id from the new list
};
```

Comment: What if I need to Check not only the Id of the car, but also the registrationNumber. Is there a way to have 2 conditions in your Select ?

Answer (score 0):

When you are saying that new cars are the source of truth, that means you want them always in the list, but you may not have an equivalent old car. You are describing a left-join.

This should get you most of what you want.

```
var results = from n in newCars
    join o in oldCars
    on n.Id == o.Id
    group into cars 
    from oc in cars.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select (NewCar: n, Present: oc != null)
```

The result is a tuple containing the new car and a boolean `Present` that is `true` or `false` based on whether there is an old car or not.

That gives you a single result set. You wanted two result sets as a tuple. To get this, just extend the above query, grouping by `Present`. This gives you a result set with exactly two items

```
var results = (from r in (from n in newCars
        join o in oldCars
        on n.Id equals o.Id
        into cars
        from oc in cars.DefaultIfEmpty()
        select (NewCar: n, Present: oc != null))
    group r by r.Present into g
    orderby g.Key descending 
    select g.Select(x => x.NewCar).ToList()).ToList();
```

from which you can get a single tuple containing both lists

```
var finalResult = (Present: results[0], Absent: results[1]);
```

Comment: I would suggest putting a `ToList` on the final `select` so that `g.Select` is processed once during the query. Also, I think your first query is missing something: doesn't `from oc.DefaultIfEmpty()` needs a range variable? And you use `n` and `newcar` as the same range variable.

Comment: What about the `from oc.DefaultIfEmpty()`? It doesn't need a range variable?

Comment: I think you were looking at a prior edit (it *was* wrong at one point). `cars.DefaultIfEmpty()` is what is needed for correct results.

Comment: No, first query see the phrase?

Comment: Oops. I'm finally getting what you're trying to say. I changed it in one code block but not the other; that's what I get for not using a compiler. Thanks for being diligent!

Answer (score 0):

Using an extension method to treat adding to a list (a tiny bit) more functionally, you can use LINQ `Aggregate` to do this in one pass:

```
var idsFromOldCars = oldCars.Select(c => c.Id).ToHashSet();
var(present, absent) = newCars.Aggregate((p:new List<Car>(),a:new List<Car>()), (pa,nc) => idsFromOldCars.Contains(nc.Id) ? (pa.p.AfterAdd(nc),pa.a) : (pa.p,pa.a.AfterAdd(nc)));
```

Where `AfterAdd` is defined in a static class as:

```
public static class ListExt {
    public static List<T> AfterAdd<T>(this List<T> head, params T[] tail) {
        head.AddRange(tail);
        return head;
    }
}
```

But it is much clearer to just use a `foreach` loop:

```
    var idsFromOldCars = oldCars.Select(c => c.Id).ToHashSet();
    var present = new List<Car>();
    var absent = new List<Car>();
    foreach (var nc in newCars) {
        if (idsFromOldCars.Contains(nc.Id))
            present.Add(nc);
        else
            absent.Add(nc);
    }
```

In both cases, creating the `HashSet` ensures you don't have to scan through the `oldCars` list to find each `newCar`. If you knew the lists were ordered by `Id`, you could do a more complicated one-pass solution traveling down the lists in parallel, but that hardly seems worth the complexity even then.

NOTE: A `Join` effectively does something similar, converting the second `List` into a `Lookup` (like a `Dictionary`) that can be used to find the matches with the first `List`.

Comment: Can I use ANY instead ? I may have more than 1 condition to match in order to categories it to present or absent ? Help.

Comment: @Illep Perhaps you can update your question to be clearer? You seem to have conflicting ideas about what you want...